# Running nginx on AWS is sending back 'ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT' responses

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, connection

I have installed nginx on an Ubuntu AWS (EC2) node and confirmed it is running via `ps -aef | grep nginx`. In the `server` section I have:

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name   ec2-<blah>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com;

    location / {
        root   /opt/derp;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

...where `ec2-<blah>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` is the public DNS of my EC2 instance.

When I reload (`sudo nginx -s reload`) and go to `http://ec2-<blah>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080`, I expect to get the default nginx "**Welcome!**" page, but instead I get HTTP failures (in Chrome `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`, which is the most info I'm getting).

To me, this could be because:

1. Perhaps I'm going to the wrong URL (user error on my end)
2. Perhaps there's some network configuring (firewall rules, etc.) I need to setup in AWS
3. Perhaps an nginx config issue
4. Perhaps a Linux user/permissions issue

I'm here to rule out (or confirm) an nginx issue. Can anyone spot anything wrong with my nginx `server` config? I can happily post other sections of my `nginx.conf` or provide any other details necessary to vet nginx as a potential problem child or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configure a security group for the instance which allows inbound tcp 8080. Also ensure a local firewall (iptables, ufw, firewalld or similar) on the instance isn't blocking the traffic.